# Execute scheduled Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function that should be executed at 6.30 am and 1.30pm. I stopped the function and the scheduled executions were not executed. When I started the function. Automatically  the function was executed even if the time was 11.am and that's not the scheduled time to run it.

Do you now if the function has like a queue to manage the scheduled executions when the function should run but it is stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have stopped the Azure Function App **manually** at your end, it is anticipated that the timer trigger will not run as per the schedule because of the Function host is not running.

As a note, the function required to be running all the time irrespective of the timer schedule.

The executions that occurred at 11 AM might be the older executions where that function might have missed when the function app was stopped.

Check the invocation details for more information and also Monitor section of your function.

***Based on the CRON Schedule, the Timer Trigger itself would trigger So there is no need for any managed queue***.